# Excel VBA Counter for PDF import

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, vba, import

I'm attempting to include a VBA script into a spreadsheet I'm making which imports 7 PDFs into a range of cells. I'm using the following code to do the import, which works fine with the exception of getting the imports where I want them. I am able get the script to choose a column. This means I use `Range("B" & Counter).Select` and `Counter = Counter + 1` it will insert the PDFs in B1 then B2 etc.

The problem I am having is that I need these to be inserted at C101. It would appear it is taking the C101 reference as a string and starting at Cell C1011 then C1012.

```
Sub AddOlEObject()

Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook

Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

Dim Counter As Integer



Folderpath = "C:\Users\benba\OneDrive - BWSC\Skrivebord\Reports\CEMs"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count

Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files

For Each fls In listfiles

    Counter = Counter + 1

    Range("B" & Counter).Select

    strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)

    If strCompFilePath <> "" Then

        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=strCompFilePath, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, IconIndex:=1, IconLabel:=strCompFilePath).Select

    End If
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! If you want the files to be inserted at Column C from row 101 onward, why is your code still mentioning column B instead of column C?

Comment: Agree. This question does not demonstrate the problem you say it does. "It would appear it is taking the C101 reference as a string and starting at Cell C1011 then C1012." What C101 reference? Yes, if you say `Range("C101" & Counter)` then you'll get `C1011` etc. So, don't do that? But we can't help you further if your code doesn't correspond to your question.

Comment: Sorry, that is just a combination of frustration and using a test spreadsheet to demo these ideas.
The point of the question was that I wanted these PDFs to be inserted further down in column, whereas as the moment with this code I can only start from the top of a chosen column. 
In my example I can use "B" to start from the top of a column, but if I was to use "C101" where I want it on my final document, it will start at C1011 and continue. 
I'm just not sure why it starts at C101+1 rather than C102, C103 etc. 
Thanks for you patience.